# There's any way, in K8S, to source an env file, dynamically generated during an initcontainer?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I'm planning to have an *initcontainer* that will handle some crypto stuff and then generate a source file to be sourced by a *container*.
The source file will be dynamically generated, the VARS will be dynamic, this means I will never know the VAR names or it's contents. This also means I cannot use k8s *env*.
The file name will always be the same.

I know I can change the Dockerfile from my applications and include an entrypoint to execute a script before running the workload to source the file, but, still, is this the only option?
There's no way to achieve this in k8s?

My *container* can mount the dir where the file was created by the *initcontainer*. But it can't, somehow, source the file?

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: pod-init
  namespace: default
spec:
  nodeSelector:
    env: sm
  initContainers:
    name: genenvfile
    image: busybox
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    command: ["/bin/sh"]
    # just an example, there will be a software here that will translate some encrypted stuff into VARS and then append'em to a file
    args: ["-c", "echo MYVAR=func > /tmp/sm/filetobesourced"]
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /tmp/sm
      name: tmpdir
  containers:
    image: gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:slim
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    name: mypod-cm
    tty: true
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /tmp/sm
      readOnly: true
      name: tmpdir
  volumes:
    name: tmpdir
    emptyDir:
      medium: Memory
```

The step-by-step that I'm thinking would be:

1. *initcontainer* mounts /tmp/sm and generates a file called /tmp/sm/filetobesourced
2. *container* mounts the /tmp/sm
3. *container* source the /tmp/sm/filetobesourced
4. workload runs using all the vars sourced by the last step

Am I missing something to get the third step done?

Comment: Does the secret has to be tightly coupled together with lifecycle of this Pod(i.e., a new secret required for each new container spin up)?

Comment: Have you tried to mount the generated file as `/etc/environment`?

Comment: @SYN I believe /etc/environment, /etc/profile, /etc/profile.d/*.sh.. or any other /etc/<stuff> will not work for the workloads. Those are executed during the login of a user. Right?

Comment: @congbaoguier yes. The encrypted "stuff" is valid only during the life of the pod.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `command` and/or `args` on the main container to be more like `bash -c 'source /tmp/sm/filetobesourced && exec whatevertheoriginalcommandwas'`.

Comment: Thx for contributing @coderanger. Still, I'm looking for something that does not change the behavior of the Dockerfile. You are asking me to override the entrypoint, right? I can't, because we have a live environment and different kinds of entrypoints(+apps) are used.
Or maybe I misunderstood your answer. Maybe you could provide an example of running something first then continue to execute the entrypoint/workload as it was meant to be.

Comment: Nope, there is no option which meets those requirements. Docker does not expose the original command in a generic way.